# How to update vendor file directly in server like composer update in local

Tags: excel, laravel, composer-php, vendor

I have one project and in half of the protect I have uploaded it to the server.
I made some changes and used excel package in my project and it worked well in local. I uploaded the file in server and it shows problem.

> Class Maatwebsite\Excel\ExcelServiceProvider not found

after that I uploaded the package to vendor and made common changes in config/app(put facade and alias) but also same problem.
Anyone know the reason???
I have tried hard. Please reply.

Answer (score 0):

the reason why you are having a class not found exception is because your vendor auto-loader class map on the remote server has not been updated yet. You should atleast re-upload the "composer" directory on your vendor directory `"vendor/composer"` as it contains all the class map that has been generated of all the packages.

Please do `composer dump-autoload` on your local development and then re-upload the **composer** directory found on your **vendo**r folder.